# Запрет ahrefs доступа к сайту в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Нашел несколько решений, но ahrefs продолжает успешно проверять сайт:

```
Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^4]* /404 [L,S=4000]

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^$" bad_user
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^AhrefsBot" bad_user
Deny from env=bad_user
```

---

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} AhrefsBot
RewriteRule (.*) - [F,L]
```

---

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "AhrefsBot" bad_bot

<Limit GET POST HEAD>
 Order Allow,Deny
 Allow from all
 Deny from env=bad_bot
</Limit>
```

Если существует возможность запрета ВСЕХ ботов, кроме гугл (или белого списка), этот вариант подойдет больше.

Comment: Не мудрите и просто пропишите AhrefsBot в robots.txt, бот его учитывает

Comment: Уже прописан, на сайте ahrefs есть информация по ссылке robot снизу страницы. Но я свободно захожу в личный кабинет ahrefs и делаю новую проверку.

Comment: Вот это: 
User-agent: AhrefsBot
Disallow: /

Comment: Возможно, вы прописали его совсем недавно и бот просто ещё не успел применить новые правила? Я на своём сайте прописал — AhrefsBot перестал меня посещать через некоторое время

Comment: Хм. Вообще роботс носит рекомендательный характер, может Вы правы, нужно подождать. Но если нашел вредоносного бота, как я могу насильно запретить ему доступ? Нужно решение при помощи .htaccess. Я нагуглил много вариантов, но сайт продолжает пускать бота. Будто бы он называется не так, как написано в правилах.

Comment: *По-настоящему вредоносного* бота вы никак не запретите. Он будет маскироваться под обычного посетителя с обычным браузером и посещать вас с множества разных IP-адресов. Некоторые достаточно умные боты даже умеют обходить капчу.